# Lagrange multipliers - maximum and minimum values given constraint

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum and minimum values of the function subject to the given constraint. (If an answer does not exist, enter DNE.)
$ \ \ f(x, y, z) = xyz \ ; \ \    x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2 = 96$

What I have gotten to:
$\Delta f = \ <yz, xz, xy>$
and $\Delta g = \ λ<2x, 4y, 6z>$

set them equal and get:
$x^2 = 2y^2$ and 
$z^2 = \frac{2}{3} y^2$ .

Then:
$$
\begin{cases}x^2 + 2y^2 +3z^2 = 96 \\
6y^2 = 96 \\
y = \pm16 \end{cases}
$$

Plugging $y$ into $z^2$ and $x^2$ equations above, you get the points:
$(\pm16\sqrt{2}, \ \pm 16, \  \pm16\sqrt{2/3} ) \ .$

Plugging the points back into $f$, I got a maximum of $32\sqrt{3}$ and a minimum of $-32\sqrt{3}$.

Where did I go wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: your edit is strange, we write $\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$.

Comment: That's what I meant. Can you help me find where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see where you used Lagrange multipliers. Any critical points will satisfy the Lagrange multipliers equation

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
yz & xz & xy
\end{bmatrix} = \lambda \begin{bmatrix}
2x & 4y & 6z
\end{bmatrix} \ .
$$

This gives you the system of equations

$$
\begin{align}
yz &= 2\lambda x & (1) \\
xz &= 4\lambda y & (2) \\
xy &= 6\lambda z & (3) \\
96 &= x^2+2y^2+3z^2 & (4)
\end{align}
$$

First consider $\lambda = 0$ and then consider other cases. Try this and see how it goes for you. I hope this helps.

EDIT:

If you assume $x,y,z\neq 0$, you can solve for $\lambda$ in each of $(1), (2), (3),$ and $(4)$. You then obtain (by equating these $\lambda$), as you did, $6y^2=96$, which gives $y=\pm4$. You similarly obtain $x^2 = 32$, or $x=\pm4\sqrt{2}$, and $z^2 = \frac{32}{3}$, or $z=\pm4\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$. With all of the $\pm$'s, you get a few critical points. Plug them in to see which ones are the largest/smallest.

Comment: assume all variables are non-zero, since otherwise f=0, and we ignore that case for the time-being.

Comment: I did use lambda. Someone edited it out by mistake.

Comment: I still need help.

Comment: @Ryan: I added some more to my answer. Hopefully this will help (and my algebra is not wrong). I did not check the critical points from the other cases, so you may have other cases to explore.

Comment: Wouldn't 6y^2 = 96, give you y = +-4?

Comment: @Ryan: Yes, sorry! I just fixed it. My mental math skills are not so good...

Comment: @Ryan: It looks like you just made a mistake when taking the square root of $x^2 = 32$ and $z^2 = 32/3$.

Comment: So, 128/root(3) would be the max value, and -128/root(3) would be the min value?

Comment: Yes, it appears so.

Answer (score 0):

With the the combination of critical points, the global max would be 128/3 and global min would be -128/3. Just any combination of multiple of negatives or positives that produces the positive(max) end and negative end(min).